# How to check a morphism is actually a morphism between functors needed to construct an adjoint characteristic

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors, natural-transformations

I am learning elementary category theory. My question was raised while I was reading a part about a characteristic of adjoint functors.

We adopt a policy for the notation $h_A(X) = \mathrm{Mor}(X, A)$ and $h^A(X) = \mathrm{Mor}(A, X)$. We use $C^\wedge$ to denote the category of presheaves on a category $C$. Thus, for $A$ being an object of a category $C$, the functor $h_A$, or $h^A$, is an object of $C^\wedge$, or $C^{\mathrm{op}\wedge}$, respectively.

Let $C, C'$ be categories. Let $F \colon C \to C'$ and $G \colon C' \to C$ be functors. We use the same notations for $F \colon C^{\mathrm{op}} \to C'^{\mathrm{op}}$ and $G \colon C'^{\mathrm{op}} \to C^{\mathrm{op}}$ We have a functor between presheaves $G^*: C^{\mathrm{op}\wedge} \to C'^{\mathrm{op}\wedge}$. Let
$$
\psi \colon h_{C'^{\mathrm{op}}} \circ F \to G^* \circ h_{C^{\mathrm{op}}}
$$
be a morphism between functors. Here, we used $h_C \colon C \to C^\wedge$ to denote a functor defined by $h_C(A) = h_A$ for an object $A$ and $h_C(f) \colon h_A \to h_B$ with $h_C(f)(X) = f_*$ for a morphism $f \colon A \to B$. We note that, actually, $h_{C^{\mathrm{op}}}(A) = h^A$ and $h_{C^{\mathrm{op}}}(f)(X) = f^*$.

For any $A$ being an object of $C$, for any $B$ being an object of $C'$, we have a function
$$
\psi (A) (B) \colon \mathrm{Mor}_{C'} (F(A), B) \to \mathrm{Mor}_C (A, G(B)).
$$

We want to define a morphism of functors
$$
\varphi \colon \mathrm{Mor}_{C'} (F(\cdot), \cdot) \to \mathrm{Mor}_C (\cdot, G(\cdot))
$$
by $\varphi(A, B) = \psi(A)(B)$. My question is how to prove that $\varphi$ is really a morphism of functors.

Let me specify notations of proof. Let $f \colon A \to B$ be a morphism of $C$ and $f' \colon A' \to B'$ be a morphism of $C'$. We consider $f \times f' \colon A \times A' \to B \times B'$. Then, what we want to prove is that the following diagram is commutative.
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Mor}_{C'} (F(B), A') @> \mathrm{Mor}_{C'} (F(\cdot), \cdot)(f \times f') >> \mathrm{Mor}_{C'} (F(A), B') \\
@V \psi(B)(A') VV @V \psi(A)(B') VV\\
\mathrm{Mor}_{C} (B, G(A')) @> \mathrm{Mor}_C (\cdot, G(\cdot)) (f \times f') >> \mathrm{Mor}_{C} (A, G(B')).
\end{CD}
$$
Let $k \colon F(B) \to A'$ be a morphism of $C'$. This commutativity is equivalent to the following equation.
$$
\psi(A)(B')(f' \circ k \circ F(f)) = G(f') \circ \psi(B)(A')(k) \circ f.
$$
I can't prove this at the moment. Therefore I have decided to post this question. I would appreciate it if you give this a proof.

Comment: To clarify, your using $h_A$ as the Yoneda embedding?

Comment: Also, your diagram is broken

Comment: In my textbook, $h_A(X) = \mathrm{Mor}(X, A)$ and $h^A(X) = \mathrm{Mor}(A, X)$. I didn't know how to say it in English (or our language) since my textbook didn't tell me how. It only used its notation. In addition, I fixed LaTeX commands to display the diagram.

Comment: Your use of $\times$ is unorthodox. Anyway, you have not used the hypothesis that $\psi$ is natural, i.e. a “morphism of functors”.

Comment: I use $\times$ as my textbook uses. It would be great if you tell me the standard notation because I’m still a stranger around category theory. I know that we should use the assumption that $\psi$ is a natural transformation to proceed more, but I have not come up with how yet.

Comment: As a side note, my textbook is “数学原論” by Prof Takeshi Saito in Japanese. http://www.utp.or.jp/book/b498553.html